# <div> with absolute position in the viewport when scrolling the page vertically

Tags: css, css-position, viewport, absolute

I created [JANITOR](https://github.com/gerib/userscripts/wiki/JANITOR-%E2%80%93-Java-API-Navigation-Is-The-Only-Rescue) which:

> Inserts a navigation tree for modules, packages and types (interfaces, classes, enums, exceptions, errors, annotations) into the Javadoc pages of Java 11+.

[image: JANITOR]

The main elements involved are:

```html
  ...
  <div id="nav&amp;mainContainer" style="display: flex;">  
    <div id="nav" style="width: 25em; height: 386px; border-right: 1px solid; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <main role="main" style="flex: 1 1 0%;">
  ...
```

How can I achieve that the navigation (`<div id="nav" ...>`) stays always at the same place left of the viewport if the page is scrolled so that visually only `<main>` is scrolled?

**UPDATE**

Using:

```html
    <div id="nav" style="position:fixed; ...>
```

as proposed in an answer:

[image: with position:fixed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the css styling "fixed"

```
<div id="nav" style="position:fixed; width: 25em; height: 386px; border-right: 1px solid; overflow-y: scroll;">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: Add margin-left on the content to the right equal to the width of the fixed div

Answer (score 2):

I created a sample example:

```css
.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.test1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
  height: auto;
  width: 70px;
}

.test2 {
  padding-left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">Hello Hello Hello
  </div>
  <div class="test2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could try those code from codepen.io/pen that what seen. I hope it'll show a path.

Comment: Thx! The `position:fixed` from the other answer and your `padding-left` did it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix any div, you could use sticky, fixed or absolute. According to your last update, you could push with padding/margin for your needs.

My advice to you, you could inspect the Javadoc pages of Java 11+. You will find easyly your answer.

When you could investigate to find your questions that be careful html element position status and left/right or padding/margin state.

```
Padding : The CSS padding properties are used to generate space around an element's content, inside of any defined borders
Margin : The CSS margin properties are used to create space around elements, outside of any defined borders.
```

Source : [CSS Padding](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)  [CSS Margin](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp)

Comment: Re „_you could inspect the Javadoc pages of Java 11+_“: Guess what I did the last two days to insert the navigation tree at all. :)